# Provide link to meta for new users

Tags: feature-request, new-users, help-center, tour

Can we give an easier path for new users to find meta? I feel like it is a little obscured.

**Visiting as a new user**

I happened to go to stackoverflow on a computer which did not automatically log me in yesterday. Before you respond "What is the world coming to"; I know, it was foolish and childish of me to not have provided my login information on my friends device when I first created my account here.

**Too Involved To Find The Meta Site**

On the front page for new users with no accounts (or for users not logged in) the word "meta" literally does not exist (although there is a "feedback" link in the footer which points to meta). Clicking "Tell me more" takes you to a visually pleasing interface, but it still does not contain "meta" at all. Click #2 will land you at the Help Center if you have lucked out to find this path as a user probably a little intimidated by the size of the site. From there, a single link exists What is "meta"? Click #3 to enter this page and find an inline link in the text to a meta search which shows questions tagged with [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

**Meta contains a wealth of knowledge that would help new users, and which continues to help longstanding users**

It would be very helpful to include a link to this [list of frequently asked meta questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=frequent) somewhere in the tour, perhaps also with a mention of `meta` so that users can browse questions about using the site. Perhaps something like this: ***[`jsFiddle Demo of structure`](http://jsfiddle.net/Hwamb/)***

[image: meta suggestion]

Comment: I think this is intentional. Otherwise, the # of off-topic questions on meta will skyrocket.

Comment: @Mysticial - The frequently asked questions list provides so much information about how to use the site though. Far more than the help center does. Just the first page of results is enough content to get a fair understanding of many nuances in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: "feedback" not doing it for you?

Comment: @random - When I searched the page, I did not search the value of the link hrefs so I did not see that feedback led to meta. Thank you for the clarification there. But I think the intention of what I am suggesting is not to get new users feedback, but to allow them to see all of the discussion that has already taken place with regards to the site. Perhaps "Participate" could be reworded. I am not saying that this text is perfect, but perhaps with slight improvement it could be helpful to drive new users to look at community consensus for a variety of issues.

Comment: A new user would find "feedback" makes more sense to them than "meta". You are a bit prejudiced having used the site for a while

Comment: @random - That is fine, I can understand that. But my point was not that new users should be shown where to provide feedback. More that they should be shown where some of the main questions about how to use the site are.

Comment: @Mysticial - How will knowing about meta cause a "skyrocket" of off-topic questions? I feel that worrying about users asking off topic questions is not applicable to allowing new users a path to be more educated about how to use the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @TravisJ As it is right now, many people can't see the difference between SO and meta.SO. The grey-color and the word "meta" doesn't mean anything until you're a bit more familiar with the site.

Comment: @Mysticial - I guess I just don't see any evidence of that. I looked at the last 150 questions just now and did not see any asking about how to obtain a pointer for the address of a List<T> in c# (or equivalent). Where is this epidemic of questions that should be on SO but are on meta?

Comment: @TravisJ They're all deleted. I count 14 of them in the last day from the 10k tools. Most of those are just question-banned users who got linked to meta from the question banned message.